# Where to place view specific logic in a project structure?

Tags: java, view, controller

I'm adding some code to my project that allows drag and drop.

The Form used for the actual dropping is obviously part of the view/presentation layer. However, there's a question mark on a `TransferHandler` class that contains the actual logic which detects and validates objects dropped on the window.

Considering I have presentation, logic and data layers, where could this class be placed in the structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is totally related to presentation layer,  then at presentation layer.

or if the same thing is needed when your presentation changes than at logic (service) layer.

Comment: Ok. So if I get this straight, the reasoning would be that it is decoupled if the presentation layer can change. The class would then be placed in the business logic.

Comment: Yes, in `MVC` ,  `V` can change at any time we should think of that more precisely.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest a presentation layer, but creating some package for example `util`, which will contain all classes you use to help your view features like drag-adnd-drop.

Comment: Good and straightforward suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Which class is the information expert, meaning the class with the most information pertaining to the operation? It seems like the presentation layer contains the class that is the information expert, thus it would be reasonable to place the code there. Should this action affect domain objects though you may want to look at implementing a use case controller which would be called from the presentation layer.

Comment: It would be the MyTransferHandler class or one calling it. It will be used to import information which will have an effect on domain objects. Thanks for mentioning the Use Case Controller pattern. I like the idea as it'll fit in with my analysis.